# ASP.NET Active Directory Authentication works locally, but not on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I have an application and I authenticating against and Active Directory and this works when I run it locally. However when I push this to a server, it does not work at all and I get a 500 error when I try to login.

This is my login method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginClass model, string ReturnUrl)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl) && ReturnUrl.Length > 1 && ReturnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !ReturnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !ReturnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                       return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect");
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

and here is some stuff in my web.config file:

```
 <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://testdomain.test.com/CN=Users,DC=testdomain,DC=test,DC=com" />

<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
    </authentication>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server, make sure the application pool is running in the context of an account with access to your Active Directory.